# calling function in constructor gives different result c++

Tags: c++

This code gives me the required result

```cpp
std::string op = _currentToken.getVal();
return new ASTBinaryExprNode(op, factor, parseExpressionTerm(), lineNumber);
```

whereas this code in syntactically correct but gives a different result

```cpp
return new ASTBinaryExprNode(_currentToken.getVal(), factor, parseExpressionTerm(), lineNumber);
```

My `ASTBinaryExprNode` is as follows:

```cpp
class ASTBinaryExprNode :public ASTExprNode {
public:
    std::string _optor;
    int _lineNumber;
    ASTExprNode* _expr1;
    ASTExprNode* _expr2;
    virtual void accept(visitor::Visitor*) override;
    ASTBinaryExprNode(std::string  optor , ASTExprNode* expr1, ASTExprNode* expr2, int lineNumber);
};
```

Declaration of `getVal` is  in `Token` class is shown below:

```cpp
class Token {
private:
    int lineNumber;

    TOKEN determineTokenType(int  finalState, std::string);
    std::string value;

public:
    int getLineNumber() { return lineNumber; }
    int getType();
    TOKEN type;
    std::string getVal() { return value; }
    Token(int  finalState, std::string, int  line_number = 0);
    Token();
};
```

I can't find what may be the cause of this problem. I solved this problem  using first code shown above but still but still unsatisfied.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but a tip, calling a virtual function in the `constructor of base` might give surprising results.

Comment: thanks for response but i have not written such code here. @arnes

Comment: @AAYUSNEUPANE also, in `constructor of base` be aware that all object is not fully instantiated, just `base class` is instantiated yet. Maybe this could be the  reason.

Comment: Is `parseExpressionTerm()` using the `std::string optor ` ?

Comment: in fact above code is inside   definition parseExpressionTerm() @Mannoj

Comment: @AAYUSHNEUPANE could you please show parseExpressionTerm()? Want to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified; the second piece of code may evaluate `parseExpressionTerm()` before `_currentToken.getVal()`, and this is what's happening.

If evaluation order matters, you need to take care of that yourself, like in the first piece of code.

Comment: Isn't it that it should evaluate left to right for parameters list?

Comment: @Mannoj No, not in C++.

Comment: @Mannoj No, the standard just guarantees that evaluation is completed before the function call. For example, gcc does right-to-left, clang left-to-right but it is not guaranteed anyway

Comment: @Mannoj left to right is guaranteed for the comma operator, not for a function's parameters list.